# Idle (not idle in transaction) connections are not released/closed in PostgreSQL AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.3, c3p0

I'm using C3P0 connection pool and PostgreSQL(10.3) in AWS RDS.

I did a load test at low TPS (1 TPS) for 2 minutes, after load test finished, the number of connections were not dropped according to the monitoring board in AWS RDS. (See below). Neither did CPU utilization.

[image]

I'm still new to database, not sure if this is expected? This seems like it's reaching RDS instance's max_connection. I did a `select` from `pg_stat_activity`, 99% of connections are `idle`, and most of the queries are `SHOW TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` and `SELECT 1`.

Here's my C3P0 config:

```
maxConnection: 100
initialPoolSize: 1
minPoolSize: 1
acquireIncrement: 1
idleConnectionTestPeriod: 40
maxIdleTime: 20
maxConnectionAge: 30
maxStatements:0
numHelperThread:5
preferredTestQuery: SELECT 1
propertyCycle: 0
testConnectionOnCheckIn: false
testConnectionOnCheckOut: false
debugUnreturnedConnectionStacktraces: false
unreturnedConnectionTimeout: 60
acquireRetryAttempts: 10
acquireRetryDelay: 1000
checkoutTimeout: 10000
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

---

Load test tool: It's a company internal load test tool. Generally speaking, it's creating loads to the service (5+ hosts) to hit my API, the API talks to connection pool to connectionPool.getDataSource().getConnection()(ComboPooledDataSource). The connection pool is a singleton instance among service, while each call to the API is in its own thread.

Comment: My guess is that C3P0 doesn't release the connections it acquired when the API talked to it. You may change the C3P0 configuration for allowing faster connections release.

Comment: Can you explain more on "allowing faster connections release"?  I already set most of the configs (e.g. max idle time) to less than 20s. Do you think all these `idle` connections are expected? I mean like - they're idle but can be re-used later. Or it should be like - the connections should be gone instead of staying as `idle`?

Comment: Try the solution proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8773410/363573